# Gatsby Component Props CSS Module

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to use a props as a class in styles, using Gatsby CSS Module

```
import styles from './header.module.sass'

const Header = props => (
    <header className={styles + props.position}>
```

I know this code doesn't work, it's just to show you what I'd like to achieve.

In my layout, I call header component like this, so header would then render using the specific css for top. I know I can easily do it without the CSS Module, but it's not the point.

```
<Header position="top" />
```

Any help or advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `props.position = 'top'` and you want to set `className={styles.top}` via the props, you could do it like this:

```
import styles from './header.module.sass'

const Header = props => (
<header className={styles[props.position]}>
```